# Wp e-commerce buy only once

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Is there a way to do, that users in WP E-commerce can add only one piece of the product to the cart?

I don't know how to do this, but I need it very much.

Answer (score 0):

i thought that you can achieve it by using maximum purchase plugin, so can set that maximum purchase to a user

for more details look at here : http://wordpress.org/plugins/maximum-purchase-for-wp-e-commerce/

Answer (score 0):

use woo E-commerce plugin and your problem will solved. For more detail visit my blog (freewebtipsforum.blogspot) and shoot me an email.